# How to have the equalizer dynamically adjust depending on volume level?

Tags: windows, audio, speakers, volume-mixer, equalizer

### Givens

I'm using my Windows 10 PC as a media source for home theater, music and gaming.

I have upgraded my speakers to a decent 2.1 setup, connected via a single line-out jack. Using the built-in audio card based on Realtek ALC1220-VB (Gigabyte markets it as high-end, but the driver is buggy garbage, randomly causing either line-out or center/cub jacks to stop working).

---

### Problem

Recently I've been digging into various audio-related concerns, and I have realized one thing: when you change the volume of the speakers/headphones, the perceivable volume of different frequencies changes unevenly.

Namely, **when you reduce the volume, the bass gradually disappears while mid and high sounds remain clearly audible**.

The opposite should also be true: setting the volume to high levels should cause the subwoofer outplay the speakers.

Music loses depth, movies lose suspense.

I am able to compensate for this in two ways:
1. After reducing the PC's volume, manually raise the subwoofer's volume.
2. After reducing the PC's volume, raise the gain on low frequencies in the audio driver's equalizer.

Both ways are really tedious.

---

### Question

**I need a way to make the adjustment automatically.**

As I lower the volume, the equalizer should gradually slope down to make bass frequencies have more gain.

As I raise the volume, the equalizer should gradually flatten out.

Ideally, the sensitivity of automatic EQ adjustment should be configurable.

---

### Bonus question

Is my concern legit in the first place? How are other people solving this problem?

Comment: The issue you hear is described by Fletcher–Munson curves.

Comment: @sawdust Oh wow, thanks! Why the hell does no hardware or software manufacturer account for those curves?!